# Odoo12 Cron Jobs Execute on specific days

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

I have  written cronjobs in odoo12 and I want them to execute 6 days in a week with exemption of sundays since sunday is not a working day, how can i do that in odoo12/odoo11

Comment: i feel the linux cron jobs offer more flexibility am not sure if the odoo erp platform developers have a solution for this challenge yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing run cron everyday but while executing the function you can skip there put condition there of not executing your function on sunday.

Comment: I actually think this makes a lot of sense